# ASP.NET listbox handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ASP.NET page with a form that contains several common text fields like this one:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="form_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="" placeholder="name" />
</div>
```

and a CountryPicker (from https://github.com/winmarkltd/BootstrapFormHelpers):

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></span>
  <div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="IT" data-flags="true" style="max-width:280px;">
    <input type="hidden" value="">
    <a class="bfh-selectbox-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="bfh-selectbox" href="#">
      <span class="bfh-selectbox-option input-medium" data-option=""></span>
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <div class="bfh-selectbox-options">
      <input type="text" class="bfh-selectbox-filter">
      <div role="listbox">
        <ul role="option"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in the submit event handler I want to retrieve the field's value:

```
public void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        var name = form_name.Text;
        //var country = ???

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(name + ", " + country);
    }
}
```

I wonder which html tag I need to replace with the asp:* one in order to read the country value.

Inspecting the actual code at runtime shows where is the current text:

[image: current text]

Then I want to enable also the TextChanged event, to know when the user change the current value.

Comment: In the client-side code, is there an element which ever holds the "country" value?  There's an `input type="hidden"` in there, maybe that's it?  You could make it `runat="server"` and give it an `id` to access it server-side.

Comment: Inspecting the actual code in the running page, shows where is the current Text. I've update the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your updated screen shot, the actual value is being stored here:

```
<input name="" type="hidden" value="IT" />
```

It looks like the browser is automatically adding a `name` attribute to this original code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="">
```

You can access that element's value as a server-side control if you make it a server control, something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" runat="server" id="CountryCode">
```

With [this `HtmlInputHidden` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputhidden(v=vs.110).aspx) you can access its value server-side:

```
var country = CountryCode.Value;
```

Comment: In order to have a valid object as "CountryCode" I had to replace that line with this one: `<asp:HiddenField id="CountryCode" runat="server" value="" />`. But its Value property is empty.

Comment: @Mark: You might not want to use an `asp:HiddenField` here as it gives you less control over the HTML that gets generated.  Compare the resulting HTML of this with the original to check for differences.  Is the client-side functionality populating the value at all?  If not then you may need to look deeper into whatever that client-side functionality is.  (Some kind of plugin I assume?)  You'll want to keep changes to that markup minimal in order to maintain that plugin's functionality.

Comment: mmm... the HTML code is *exactly* the same as before. I'm afraid the backend logic of `Bootstrap Form Helpers` updates the code at run-time.

Comment: @Mark: If everything is *exactly* the same then there would be no difference in the resulting functionality.  Surely *something* is happening differently.  I can't really know though, as I can't see what's on your screen.